# Eclipse navigation shortcuts

Tags: eclipse, navigation, keyboard-shortcuts

I wish to know which are the Eclipse navigation keyboard shortcuts.

I already use:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>UP</kbd> or <kbd>DOWN</kbd> to navigate trough methods

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> or <kbd>.</kbd> to navigate between errors

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page UP</kbd> or <kbd>DOWN</kbd> to navigate between tabs

<kbd>UP</kbd> or <kbd>DOWN</kbd> to navigate trough project structure at "Package Explorer" and <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to expand/collapse folders or open files

With those I almost don't use the mouse, I want to know if there's a shortcut to swap between the eclipse inner windows (to console bottom, to code middle, tasks right, explorer left and so on)

Thanks

Comment: You are aware you can modify a ton of (and enable a ton of) shortcuts via the preferences in Eclipse, correct?  It is a good place to discover this kind of thing, as well.

Comment: Thank's I'll search it better, I never stop to read those. :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a very powerful shortcut `Ctrl+3` that allows you to go pretty much anywhere. Just type `Ctrl+3` and then start typing the name of the view, e.g. "console".

Of course you can always set dedicated shortcuts for different views in `Preferences->Keys`, like `Show View (View: Console)`

Comment: Wow, that's right I'm talking about. Really thank you. I can now stop using my mouse ^^

Comment: it also has great defaults, superb hint!

Answer (score 2):

Following BlackVegetable tip & rgerganov answer I discovered the shortcuts I want:

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> <kbd>P</kbd> = View: Package Explorer

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd> = View: Console

And most are accessed by <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Best answer for me is [rgerganov's answser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11247928/912046) as it can lead anywhere?

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> = Open **Quick access** menu

You can also use:

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> = Switch Editors

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F6</kbd> = Switch Editors (reverse)

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> = Switch Views

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> = Switch Views (reverse)

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> = Switch Perspective

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> = Switch Perspective (reverse)